# Vue 3 + Vite image URL becomes undefined after build

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bundler, vite, esbuild

I encountered a bug where I dynamically generated a URL from props for image import in my Vue 3 component and it becomes undefined after build

- Script used to generate URL and the tag in Vue Component

```
const imagePath = computed(() => { return new URL(`../assets/${props.imgPath}.png`,
    import.meta.url).href

<img :src="imagePath" />
```

- Undefined URL after build
  `<img class="img" src="http://localhost:4173/undefined />`

Only two out of the many images are undefined after build which makes it very hard to pin down the problem

I tried messing around with vite.config.ts, particularly assetInlineLimit under the build section but so far nothing works

Comment: Could you try ```<img :src="require(`../assets/${props.imgPath}.png`)" />```

Answer (score 7):

I am a bit late. But for anyone still having this problem,

Similar to OP, this will not work.
It will return **undefined**. (http://localhost:5173/src/assets/icons/undefined)

```
const src = computed(() => {
    return new URL(`@/assets/icons/${props.src}`, import.meta.url);
});
```

Simply move the template literals into a variable.
And everything should work now.

```
const src = computed(() => {
    const path = new URL('@/assets/icons/', import.meta.url);
    return `${path}/${props.src}`
});
```

Apparently, **new URL** does not work well with template literals.
there's multiple bug report on this, and might be fixed in the future.
I am using **vite 4.0** as of writing this post.

Comment: works for development build, but not in production. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue and found that you need to set the build target to 'es2020' since import.meta.url is not defined in the default build target.  There is a small note at the bottom of this page:   https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, solution in my case, the image name must be like props name because it's case sensitive so I changed image name from "myimage.png" to "myiMage.png"